# Inserting table in product tabs is forced to the bottom

Tags: backend, table

I can't seem to find a solution for this but whenever I try to add a table in the products tab in the backend, the frontend will show the table forced down to the bottom of the page. Images and any other code seems to work normally and have it flushed to the top like it suppose to.

[image: normal table code]
backend

[image: table is forced down to the bottom of the page]
frontend

I tired placing it in a DIV layer with it aligned to the top. No luck...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Open:

/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml

Find:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description), 'description') ?>
```

Change to:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
```

Comment: No luck... still the same result...

Comment: Are you sure you are in your template?

Comment: positive. It actually already had the bottom code. still shows the table flushed to the bottom...